# Dashboard for Puppet 4

Tags: puppet, theforeman

Unfortunately, [The Foreman](http://theforeman.org/) still doesn't support Puppet 4 and it does not seem it will in the foreseeable future. We very much like the monitoring feature (especially seeing the outcomes of Puppet runs in the past) for ourselves and for the many developers that use our Puppet platform.

Does anyone have any experience with a dashboard alternative for Puppet 4? Are there other ways to easily track the outcomes for Puppet runs when considering around 200 different machines owned by different teams?

Comment: Foreman 1.12 Release Notes indicates that The Foreman now supports Puppet 4: https://www.theforeman.org/manuals/1.12/index.html#Releasenotesfor1.12

Answer (score 3):

Most Puppet GUI's and Dashboards use reporting from PuppetDB, so as long as you have PuppetDB in your infra they will work, regardless of your Puppet version.

(Full disclosure I work at Puppet!)

**Puppet Enterprise**:
[image: Puppet Enterprise]
**Commercial - Free for up to 10 nodes**

**Screenshot here**

https://puppet.com/download-puppet-enterprise

**Puppet Explorer:**

[image: Puppetexplorer]

**Open Source**

https://github.com/spotify/puppetexplorer

Pretty nifty, has a live search function using puppetdbquery (so you can do easy searches across your esta `(processorcount=4 or processorcount=8) and kernel=Linux`. Puppet ended up rolling the ideas of puppetdbquery into Puppet internally as PQL https://docs.puppet.com/puppetdb/4.0/api/query/v4/pql.html

**PuppetBoard:**

https://github.com/voxpupuli/puppetboard

[image: puppetboard]

**Open Source**
Python frontend for PuppetDB, used by Openstack's infra team.

**With regard to Foreman:**
Foreman 4 support is not that far of I believe. Nightlies can currently be built with Puppet 4 packages, the main thing left is the smart-proxy upgrades to work with the new Puppet 4 internals, but the PR for that is happening right now and seems like it might be merged soon! (https://github.com/theforeman/smart-proxy/pull/406). Full ticket here: http://projects.theforeman.org/issues/8447

EDIT: Foreman now has Puppet 4 Support: https://www.theforeman.org/manuals/1.12/index.html#Releasenotesfor1.12

Comment: Have been using PuppetDB for almost a year now and have been very happy with it.